# in R, can I stop print(cat("")) from returning NULL? and why does cat("foo") return foo>

Tags: r, concatenation, paste, cat

If I enter

```
print(cat(""))
```

I get

```
NULL
```

I want to use `cat()` to print out the progress of an R script, but I don't understand why it is returning `NULL` at the end of all of my concatenated strings, and more importantly, how to get it to stop?

Comment: Could you please add some clarification?  How are you running this R script (e.g. via `Rscript`, `source()`, etc)?  Where do you want to print the progress (e.g. the console, a file)?

Comment: `cat("foo")` returns returns `foo>` because you forgot to append a newline to the end of your string. R does what you ask and prints out the string `"foo"` and then prints the prompt `>`. Try `cat("foo\n")` for example, or better, `writeLines("foo")`. I've put a few examples of the latter in my answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All your answers are in the documentation for `?cat`.  The portions that answer your specific question are:

> ### Arguments:
>
> ```
> fill: a logical or (positive) numeric controlling how the output is
>       broken into successive lines.  If ‘FALSE’ (default), only
>       newlines created explicitly by ‘"\n"’ are printed.
>       Otherwise, the output is broken into lines with print width
>       equal to the option ‘width’ if ‘fill’ is ‘TRUE’, or the value
>       of ‘fill’ if this is numeric.  Non-positive ‘fill’ values
>       are ignored, with a warning.
> ```

... and ...

> ### Value:
>
> ```
>  None (invisible ‘NULL’).
> ```

So you can't stop `print(cat(...))` from returning `NULL` because that's what `cat` returns.  And you need to explicitly add newlines like `cat("foo\n")`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I did read the documentation before posting the question, but it was still not clear to me if there was a way to stop it from printing "NULL" or why it prints null or why the value is "None" even though it clearly returns the string provided... I guess some of my misunderstanding is more related to the theoretical than the practical.

Comment: Well, the documentation can be terse and `print` and `cat` may seem like they do similar things.  But `cat` _does not_ return the string provided, it _prints_ it.  Subtle, but important, difference.  It's also good practice to glance at the documentation pages for the functions in the "See Also" section.

Comment: as mentioned in response to @gunkster, I don't think I can get line breaks with paste() ...

Comment: @David - you can get newlines if you insert them: `cat(paste("foo","fi","\n","\n","bar\n"))` or `writeLines(paste("foo","fi","\n","\n","bar\n"))` for example. Or see my answer for a way of using `strwrap()` and `writeLines()` to handle wrapping in a nice clean manner.

Comment: @ucfagls: you don't need both `cat(paste(...))`.  `cat` automatically separates arguments with a space... which saves some typing. ;-)

Comment: One-line summary: `cat()` is an alternative to **both** `print(paste(...)...)`. It does both the pasting and displaying, with optional separators and labels.

Answer (score 15):

NULL is the return value of "cat()". If you omit the outer "print()" you won't see the NULL.

Comment: Not sure if this is GUI dependent. I'm using RStudio.

Answer (score 8):

I have had the exact same problem. In a nutshell, `cat()` is a little wonky under R. You didn't go into great detail about how you are trying to use `cat()` but I would suggest looking at `paste()`.

`?paste`

I think it may be what you are looking for.

Comment: I started with the paste() function, but I couldn't get it to add line breaks, and cat() was recommended to me when I asked the r-help list about line breaks : http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e12/help/10/10/0104.html

Comment: @David - a `paste()` version of the example in that R-help message would be: `writeLines(paste("msg1","msg2", sep = "\n"))`. A version using `cat()` is not so nice as you have to add an extra `"\n"`: `cat(paste("msg1","msg2","\n", sep = "\n"))` or `cat(paste("msg1","msg2", sep = "\n"), "\n")`

Answer (score 6):

I do not see the need to use `print(cat())`. To printing a message  `cat()` is already sufficient. This may be what you are looking for:

```
  for (j in 1:n) {
     cat("Running loop", j, "of", n, "\n")
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

For this, I often use `writeLines()`, in combination with `strwrap()`, and `paste()` to combine say the loop value if I'm printing out info on the current iteration. `strwrap()` handles wrapping long lines as required, and `writeLines()` means I don't have to remember to add a `"\n"` on the end of my `cat()` calls.

```
> writeLines(strwrap("a very very very very long long long long long long long long string, that is too wide for the current pager width"))
a very very very very long long long long long long long long string,
that is too wide for the current pager width
```

Here is an example using it to print out an iteration indicator:

```
for(i in 1:1000) {
    if(isTRUE(all.equal(i %% 100, 0)))
        writeLines(strwrap(paste("Iteration", i)))
    ## do something
}
```

Gives:

```
> for(i in 1:1000) {
+     if(isTRUE(all.equal(i %% 100, 0)))
+         writeLines(strwrap(paste("Iteration", i)))
+     ## do something
+ }
Iteration 100
Iteration 200
Iteration 300
Iteration 400
Iteration 500
Iteration 600
Iteration 700
Iteration 800
Iteration 900
Iteration 1000
```

Comment: Thanks for tip on strwrap, never heard of that. Apparently stop and warning uses similar approach, so manual breaks are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign it to a variable, for use in a LOOP of *apply or function (x), try this:

```
x<-eval(paste0(name,".y"))
```

The name is the variable, the ".y" adds a string to it, paste says to print in, eval evaluates the print, <- assigns it to a variable, and ax is that variable.

Answer (score 0):

I had a little bit of a different issue in that I wanted to concatenate some html text to wrap long strings in my Rmarkdown and was getting that same NULL from the `cat()`. Simply wrapping in `HTML()` from the shiny package solved the problem.

````
```{r, results = "asis"}
HTML(cat("<span style='white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-all;'>",comments,"</span>"))
````